# error: cannot find symbol - when new class is added tand imported in an existing gradle project in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, compiler-errors, importerror

I got to work with an existing java code base which uses gradle. I had to create a new class and import it in an existing class. When I run `gradle build` or `gradle bootRun` it gives the following error and build fails.

> error: cannot find symbol
>
> import com.someservice.generic.model.SomeNewClass;
>
> ```
>                                 ^
> ```
>
> symbol:   class SomeNewClass
>
> location: package com.someservice.generic.model
>
> Note: Some input files
>   use unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with
>   -Xlint:unchecked for details. 1 error  FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
>
>   > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

My new class looks like as follow,

```
package com.someservice.generic.model;

public class SomeNewClass {


}
```

And I import it as

```
import com.someservice.generic.model.RUnregPatient;
```

I have referred following questions

[Getting "cannot find Symbol" in Java project in Intellij](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12132003/getting-cannot-find-symbol-in-java-project-in-intellij/41072533)

[Can't compile java class in Intellij Idea due to "cannot find symbol class X" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20314268/cant-compile-java-class-in-intellij-idea-due-to-cannot-find-symbol-class-x-er?rq=1)

and tried reimporting, invalidatite cache and restarting, rebuilding as suggested. None of them worked for me.

Comment: On IntelliJ, go to File -> Settings -> Project Settings -> Compiler -> Java Compiler, and on the right-hand side, for Additional command line parameters enter "-Xlint:unchecked". After that, compile again and paste the error in your post

Comment: @Villat thanks for the comment. Somehow when I deleted the class file and created a new one it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting the new class file and creating another one solved the issue somehow.

Comment: I had a similar experience and it's solved by moving the class to a different package and then moving it back.